# What is the difference between `sed -i -e` and `sed -ie`?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

What is the difference between `sed -i -e` and `sed -ie` ?
It's not very clear from help
`sed --help`

```
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed
```

In second case it creates some backup file?

In general Unix utils do not permit to combine flags?

Just an example to show what is happening:

```
echo "bla" > 1.txt
cat 1.txt
bla
sed -i -e 's:bla:blakva:g' 1.txt
cat 1.txt
blakva
sed -ie 's:bla:blakva:g' 1.txt
cat 1.txt
blakvakva
*Note: also 1.txte is created, containing
cat 1.txte
blakva
```

Also not still sure what is `-e` doing in my example, because `sed -i 's:bla:blakva:g' 1.txt` works too.

Comment: What is the difference? Nothing. You can use `-i -e` or `-ie` (unless there is another option specifically defined as `ie`) As long as your expression follows `-i` you can eliminate the `e` altogether.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin see example in update.

Comment: Sure seems to be working as indicated `:)` But see sat's answer. Anything following `-i` is considered an extension to add to the original file as a back-up. Generally you would use `-i.bak` to save the original as `file.txt.bak`.

Comment: As @sat has provided the correct answer, I would point out that the following statement is completely false :- In general Unix utils do not permit to combine flags? ...  A large amount of command allow the combining of switches/options

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you give `sed -i -e`, `sed` sees two options.

But, When you give `sed -ie`, `sed` sees `-i` option only with `suffix` as `e`. That is the reason you got file backup with `e` suffix.

> From `man sed`:
>
> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)

Answer (score 6):

Option `-i` means that it modify in-place the file you are sed-ing. Otherwise `sed` just show what modification were done. If you add a suffix after `-i` (e.g `-i.bck`) it will backup your input file then add the suffix provided.

Option `-e` allow you to provide sed script instead of command line arguments.

Comment: Not still sure what is `-e` doing in my example, because `sed -i 's:bla:blakva:g' 1.txt` work too.